# Rate limiting udp packets destined to a linux machine

Tags: networking, linux-networking

Is there any way to ratelimit udp packets destined to my linux machine? I am sensing some udp packet drops destined to my machine.

Was there any default udp rate limiting conf in linux? I have seen icmp rate limit conf in  `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/icmp_ratelimit`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible with the `recent` iptables module. For [here](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/187):

```
iptables -I INPUT -p udp -i eth0 -m state --state NEW -m recent \
    --update --seconds 60 --hitcount 10 -j DROP
```

Or if you want to limit ICMP packets, you can do this with

```
iptables -I INPUT -p icmp -i eth0 -m state --state NEW -m recent \
    --update --seconds 60 --hitcount 10 -j DROP
```

The packet limiter (which is the `recent` iptables-module) are independent from the conditions, on which type packets is needs to work.

You can specify a time interval and a packet threshold. This example will enable only 10 udp packet in 1 minute.

You want probably to limit not the udp communication in general, but only the destination port. For example, this can be useful if you want to stop a not really hard DNS DDOS attack. In this case, you should give a port number as well, with the flag `--dport 53`.

The `/proc` file you mentioned, is about the icmp packets. It hasn't anything to do with udp.

Good luck!

Comment: oh.. Then then there wont be any default rate limiting for udp.. Am i right?

Comment: Yes, there is a limiter for everything. In my example there is a limit for _all_ udp packets. I extended my answer with the icmp example.